# Generate vector from a KMeans time series model

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, model

So I am doing a time series assigment and I have one requirement that is: after creating a Kmeans model and fitting the data. Generate a vector knowing to which group belongs each time series. This vector has as much dimensions as the clusters you have defined in your Kmeans model.

I am using this dataset: https://github.com/plotly/datasets/blob/master/all_stocks_5yr.csv

This is what I have for the moment:

```
import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
import matplotlib
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tslearn.clustering import TimeSeriesKMeans
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

gp = df.groupby("Name")
my_dict = {} 
for record in gp: 
   if record[0] in my_dict:
       my_dict[record[0]].append(record)
   else:
       my_dict[record[0]] = [record]

print(my_dict)
my_dict = df.rolling(window=10, min_periods=1).mean()

sc= MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_df = sc.fit_transform(my_dict) #my_dict is a dictionary dataframe containing companies separated by name.

train, test = train_test_split(scaled_df, test_size = 0.2, random_state=12345)
model = TimeSeriesKMeans(n_clusters=3, metric="dtw", max_iter=5)
model.fit(train)
```

An example of my_dict data (the key of each dataframe is the company name and the data is the date and the close column):

[image]

Does anyone know how to do this requirement? help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what the schema of `my_dict` is at the end of the for loop? it is not clear what you are creating.

Comment: Also, please give the import statements.

Comment: I edited the upper post for you to see the dictionary more clear. @SteeleFarnsworth

Comment: If `model.fit(train)` worked, then `model.predict(test)` should give you an array of predictions. A one-dimensional array is a vector, so that might be what the assignment is referring to.